# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable Monte Carlo

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, montecarlo

I know this is a fairly common question but looking at other answers for this has not helped me as I do not understand the problem exactly. I get the actual error itself but this problem is only occurring in one of the editions of my code where this line is the same in both that is the issue.

Here is version one:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#S[i, j] = 1 (spin up)
#S[i, j] = -1 (spin down)

def InitSpins(S, N):
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            S[i, j] = 2*rnd.randint(2)-1
    return S

def GenerateMove(S, N):
    i = rnd.randint(N)
    j = rnd.randint(N)
    return i, j, S[i][j], - S[i][j]

def ComputeEnergy(S, N):
    E = 0.0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            E += -J*S[i,j]*S[(i+1)%N,j] - J*S[i,j]*S[i,(j+1)%N] - H*S[i,j]
    return E

def ComputeDiffEnergy(S, i, j, old, new, N):
    Eold = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
    S[i,j] = new
    Enew = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
    S[i,j] = old
    return Enew - Eold

def MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T):
    i,j,old,new = GenerateMove(S, N)
    DE = ComputeDiffEnergy(S, i, j, old, new, N)
    if np.any(DE <= 0) or np.any(rnd.random() < np.exp(-DE/T)):
        AcceptMove(S, i, j, old, new, N)
        E += DE
        nacc += 1
#    elif 
#        AcceptMove(S, i, j, old, new, N)
#        E += DE
#        nacc += 1
    else:
        RejectMove(S, i, j, old, new, N)
    return E, nacc

def AcceptMove(S, i, j, old, new, N):
    S[i, j] = new

def RejectMove(S, i, j, old, new, N):
    S[i, j] = old

def ComputeX(S, N):
   X = 0.0
   for i in range(N):
       for j in range(N):
           X += S[i,j]
   X += 1/(N**2)*np.sum(X)
   return X

N = 10 #dimension of lattice
NIter = 10000 #iterations for production run
NEquil = NIter//10 #iterations in actual calculation
NT = 100 #number of time steps
T = 2.4
H = 0.0 #set outside magnetisation
J = 1.0 #set internal magnetisation
S = np.empty([N, N]) #set initlal spin array

S = InitSpins(S, N)
print(S)
print('energy',ComputeEnergy(S, N))

# Equilibration:
nacc = 0
E = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
for i in range(NEquil):
    E, nacc = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T)

# Production run
nacc = 0
sum_E = 0.0
sum_E2 = 0.0
E = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
for i in range(NIter):
    E, nacc = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T)
    sum_E += E
    sum_E2 += E**2

X = ComputeX(S, N)

def SumX(X, N):
    sum_X = 0.0
    sum_X2 = 0.0
    for i in range(NIter):
        sum_X += X
        sum_X2 += X**2
    return sum_X, sum_X2

sum_X, sum_X2 = SumX(X, N)

# Calculate averages
av_E = sum_E/float(NIter)
av_E2 = sum_E2/float(NIter)
av_X = sum_X/float(NIter)
av_X2 = sum_X2/float(NIter)
CV = 1/(1*(T**2))*(av_E2-av_E**2)
chi = 1/1*(T**2)*(av_X2-av_X**2)
#M = 

# print results
print("acceptance ratio",nacc/float(NIter))
print("average energy",av_E)
print("heat capacity",CV)
print("magnetic susceptibility", chi)
#print("magnetisation, )
```

This, though incomplete, gives me results.
Then I tried to make python run through a range of `T` (temperature) to give me a graph of the changing heat capacity. This breaks my `GenerateMove` function with the error given in the title for the `return i,j, S[i][j], -S[i][j]`.

Updated code that doesn't work is:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#S[i, j] = 1 (spin up)
#S[i, j] = -1 (spin down)

def InitSpins(S, N):
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            S[i, j] = 2*rnd.randint(2)-1
    return S

def GenerateMove(S, N):
    i = rnd.randint(N)
    j = rnd.randint(N)
    return i, j, S[i][j], - S[i][j]


def ComputeEnergy(S, N):
    E = 0.0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            E += -J*S[i,j]*S[(i+1)%N,j] - J*S[i,j]*S[i,(j+1)%N] - H*S[i,j]
    return E

def ComputeDiffEnergy(S, i, j, old, new, N):
    Eold = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
    S[i,j] = new
    Enew = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
    S[i,j] = old
    return Enew - Eold

def MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T):
    i,j,old,new = GenerateMove(S, N)
    DE = ComputeDiffEnergy(S, i, j, old, new, N)
    if np.any(DE <= 0) or np.any(rnd.random() < np.exp(-DE/T)):
        AcceptMove(S, i, j, old, new, N)
        E += DE
        nacc += 1
#    elif 
#        AcceptMove(S, i, j, old, new, N)
#        E += DE
#        nacc += 1
    else:
        RejectMove(S, i, j, old, new, N)
    return E, nacc

def AcceptMove(S, i, j, old, new, N):
    S[i, j] = new

def RejectMove(S, i, j, old, new, N):
    S[i, j] = old

def ComputeX(S, N):
   X = 0.0
   for i in range(N):
       for j in range(N):
           X += S[i,j]
   X += 1/(N**2)*np.sum(X)
   return X

N = 10 #dimension of lattice
NIter = 10000 #iterations for production run
NEquil = NIter//10 #iterations in actual calculation
NT = 100 #number of time steps
T = np.linspace(0.1,5.0,NT) #set temperaure range
C = np.zeros(NT) #inital heat capacity
H = 0.0 #set outside magnetisation
J = 1.0 #set internal magnetisation
S = np.empty([N, N]) #set initlal spin array

S = InitSpins(S, N)
print(S)
print('energy',ComputeEnergy(S, N))

## Equilibration:
#nacc = 0
#E = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
#for i in range(NEquil):
#    E, nacc = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T)
#
## Production run
#nacc = 0
#sum_E = 0.0
#sum_E2 = 0.0
#E = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
#for i in range(NIter):
#    E, nacc = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T)
#    sum_E += E
#    sum_E2 += E**2

X = ComputeX(S, N)

def SumX(X, N):
    sum_X = 0.0
    sum_X2 = 0.0
    for i in range(NIter):
        sum_X += X
        sum_X2 += X**2
    return sum_X, sum_X2

sum_X, sum_X2 = SumX(X, N)

for t in range(NT):
    nacc = 0
    sum_E  = 0.0
    sum_E2 = 0.0
    S = InitSpins(S, N)
    E = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
    for i in range(NIter):
        S = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T[t])
        for i in range(NEquil):
            S = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T[t])
            E, nacc = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T)
            sum_E += E
            sum_E2 += E**2
        av_E = sum_E/float(NIter)
        av_E2 = sum_E2/float(NIter)
        C[t] = (sum_E/(float(NIter*N*N)) - sum_E*sum_E/(NIter*NIter*N*N))/T[t]**2

# Calculate averages
av_X = sum_X/float(NIter)
av_X2 = sum_X2/float(NIter)
CV = 1/(1*(T**2))*(av_E2-av_E**2)
chi = 1/1*(T**2)*(av_X2-av_X**2)
#M = 

# print results
print("acceptance ratio",nacc/float(NIter))
print("average energy",av_E)
print("heat capacity",CV)
print("magnetic susceptibility", chi)
#print("magnetisation, )

#plotting resultts
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(T, C)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-52258536ecbb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/adv. numerical project graph.py', wdir='F:')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "F:/adv. numerical project graph.py", line 121, in <module>
    S = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T[t])

  File "F:/adv. numerical project graph.py", line 42, in MCStep
    i,j,old,new = GenerateMove(S, N)

  File "F:/adv. numerical project graph.py", line 24, in GenerateMove
    return i, j, S[i][j], - S[i][j]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post *the entire stack trace* and not just the error message. I understand entirely that the stack trace doesn't make much sense to you, but that doesn't mean it is meaningless, only that you don't know how to extract that meaning. You have presented quite a lot of code and it is hard for us to comb through it to find where the problem is. The stack trace would enable us to see at once where the problem is and suggest a solution.

Comment: @BoarGules I tried to edit the post to add it in but it won't let me save the changes?

Comment: Umm, I'm not a Stack Overflow meta expert, but this might explain why you can't edit your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73754/why-i-cant-edit-my-own-question

Comment: @BoarGules it seems to have let me do it now, I've added the traceback at the end (I think thats the right thing?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unnecessarily complicated your code. The extension of your first code for a fixed temperature to a range of temperatures is quite straightforward. All you had to do was to club your code performing the lattice initialization, MC equilibration and MC production runs in a `for` loop running over the given temperature range. I have created lists to store the heat capacity, chi, and average energy at each temperature.

Below is how it's done. I am choosing 30 temperature values instead of 100 so as to quickly give you a working solution. I am only showing the relevant code. Rest of the code with function definitions stay the same.

I am not comfortable with the behavior of your MC predicted heat capacity. It is supposed to increase with temperature. You need to cross check your implementation. You have everything now.

```
NT = 30 # number of temperature steps
T_list = np.linspace(0.1, 5.0, NT) # set temperaure range
av_E_list, CV_list, chi_list = [], [], []

for T in T_list: # <--- Loop over different temperatures
    print ("Performing MC for T = %.2f" %T)
    S = np.empty([N, N]) #set initlal spin array
    S = InitSpins(S, N)

    # Equilibration:
    nacc = 0
    E = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
    for i in range(NEquil):
        E, nacc = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T)

    # Production run
    nacc = 0
    sum_E = 0.0
    sum_E2 = 0.0
    E = ComputeEnergy(S, N)
    for i in range(NIter):
        E, nacc = MCStep(S, N, E, nacc, T)
        sum_E += E
        sum_E2 += E**2

    X = ComputeX(S, N)
    sum_X, sum_X2 = SumX(X, N)

    # Calculate averages
    av_E = sum_E/float(NIter)
    av_E2 = sum_E2/float(NIter)
    av_X = sum_X/float(NIter)
    av_X2 = sum_X2/float(NIter)
    CV = 1/(1*(T**2))*(av_E2-av_E**2)
    chi = 1/1*(T**2)*(av_X2-av_X**2)
    CV_list.append(CV)
    chi_list.append(chi)
    av_E_list.append(av_E)

# Plotting 
plt.plot(T_list, CV_list, '-b*')
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185954/discussion-on-answer-by-bazingaa-python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscrip).

Comment: If a user is below 20 rep, you will have to flag a post to request a moderator to move the comments into a chat room. Otherwise after 25 comments, moderators will get an auto flag on the post.